# How to connect to UR Sim from ROS?

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, universal-robots, universal-robot, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the UR Sim 3.4.5-100 for simulating the Universal Robots on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to run the simulation from ROS-Industrial (Indigo) universal_robot package. I noticed that for UR version 3.x we need to use the ur_mordern_driver package. However, the tutorial on  link:[http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20a%20Universal%20Robot%20and%20ROS-Industrial]  does not tell on how to connect to a simulated Universal Robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276468/how-to-connect-to-ur-sim-from-ros?/) by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no difference between connecting to a real or a simulated robot.

Only the IP that you connect *to* will change: instead of specifying the IP of the robot controller, you specify the IP of the computer running ursim.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:
Note btw: I'm not sure whether `ur_modern_driver` is compatible with version `3.4.5-100` systems.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2017-11-22**:
Thanks!
The command:

```
roslaunch ur_bringup ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=IP_OF_THE_ROBOT [reverse_port:=REVERSE_PORT]
```

can be used and I just need to specify the IP of the computer running URsim?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:
No. Not if you want to use `ur_modern_driver`.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2017-11-22**:
Alright, Could you please tell me how to set up the URsim to receive commands from ur_driver?
Thanks

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:
I believe there is some confusion here: you stated you wanted to use `ur_modern_driver`. Now you are asking about `ur_driver`. Those are two different packages. You cannot use launch files from `ur_bringup` with `ur_modern_driver`.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2017-11-22**:
I'm sorry, I didn't frame my question correctly. I will use the ur_driver as you suggested. I'd like to know how to configure UR Sim to receive commands from ROS.
I believe to run commands from ROS to UR Sim should be:
roslaunch <launch_file> robot_ip: <local_host>

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:
`ur_driver` is definitely not compatible with `3.4.5-100`. See the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/universal_robot) (*Compatibility* section).

You'll have to use `ur_modern_driver`, but even there I'm not sure it's compatible already with `3.4.5-100`.

If you can, try an older version of ursim.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-22**:\

> I'd like to know how to configure UR Sim to receive commands from ROS

There is no configuration, everything is taken care of by the driver.

> I believe to run commands from ROS to UR Sim should be: `roslaunch <launch_file> robot_ip: <local_host>`

yes, that's about it.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2017-11-23**:
Perfect, Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-12-04**:
I got the `3.4.5-100` working with the `ur_modern_driver`.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-02**:
Hi @gvdhoorn  and @arunavanag, how did you configure the network connection on UR-Sim. I'm using UR-sim 3.1.18024 with ur_modern_driver. It says on the Universal robot website: "Furthermore touch screen set-up and network set-up from within the GUI won't work. Its able to communicate via TCP/IP"

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-02**:
There is nothing to configure. ursim opens all its ports on the IP address(es) of the PC that you run it on. You don't configure anything in polyscope.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-03-02**:
Hi, I created a quick guide for ursim for the version i was using. See if it helps: https://github.com/arunavanag591/ursim

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-05**:
Thanks a lot. It works now, I was making an error entering the IP of the robot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-05**:
I'm slightly confused. Was:

> instead of specifying the IP of the robot controller, you specify the IP of the computer running ursim.

not clear?

@arunavanag's guide does not seem to deal with networking setup/issues.

**Comment by [prajval10](https://answers.ros.org/users/32722/prajval10/) on 2018-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn, I was involved in other stuff after initially asking this question (in Nov '17), I just got back to working on the UR Sim again now. Yes, it was just the issue of specifying the IP of the computer running ursim.
Thanks once again.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-03-05**:
@gvdhoorn there should be no issue with network and ursim, as it launches as local. Also for ur_modern_driver could be connected just by using ROBOT_IP as localhost. As you said earlier: "There is nothing to configure. ursim opens all its ports on the IP address(es) of the PC that you run it on."

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2018-03-05**:
The only known issues with ursim are the **file permissions** and **java version** if multiple java versions are installed.